# Rails - How to set global instance variables in initializers?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, controller, initializer

I was using the [predictor](https://github.com/Pathgather/predictor) gem. I initialized the recommender in `initializers/predictor.rb`:

```
require 'course_recommender'    

recommender = CourseRecommender.new

# Add records to the recommender.
recommender.add_to_matrix!(:topics, "topic-1", "course-1")
recommender.add_to_matrix!(:topics, "topic-2", "course-1")
recommender.add_to_matrix!(:topics, "topic-1", "course-2")
```

And then I wanted to use the recommender in the CourseController like this:

```
class CourseController < ApplicationController
  def show
    # I would like to access the recommender here.
    similiar_courses = recommender.similarities_for("course-1")
  end
end
```

**How could I set `recommender` as an application controller variable so I could access it in the controllers?**

Answer (score 47, accepted):

In your `initilizers/predictor.rb` you shall define your recommender not as:

```rb
recommender = CourseRecommender.new
```

but as:

```rb
Recommender = CourseRecommender.new
```

this way you define a constant throughout the scope of your application, instead of defining a local variable. In your initializer and controller you access it as `Recommender`.

Comment: Is `::` needed if we're in an initializer?  Would this already be within the global namespace?

Comment: I think `::` is not needed, since it is where the constant is defined.

Answer (score 7):

I solve the problem. But instead of setting a global instance, I use the [Singleton](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/singleton/rdoc/Singleton.html) pattern.

Here's the code:

```
# lib/course_recommender.rb
require 'singleton'
class CourseRecommender
  include Predictor::Base
  include Singleton
  # ...
end

# initializers/predictor.rb
@recommender = CourseRecommender.instance

# Add records to the recommender.
@recommender.add_to_matrix!(:topics, "topic-1", "course-1")
@recommender.add_to_matrix!(:topics, "topic-2", "course-1")
@recommender.add_to_matrix!(:topics, "topic-1", "course-2")

# controllers/course_controller.rb
require 'course_recommender'
class CourseController < ApplicationController
  def show
    similiar_courses = CourseRecommender.instance.similarities_for("course-1")
  end
end
```

Comment: This is a much cleaner and more maintainable pattern than the accepted answer, especially for testing.

Comment: I agree with @xiy, but this highlights a problem with Stack Exchange sites.  They fail to distinguish between the _question_ and the _problem_.  This answer solves the _problem_ behind the question, but the accepted answer actually answers the question (because the question assumed a particular sort of solution when it was asked).  This exposes a simplistic data model used by Stack Exchange sites.

Answer (score 1):

I am not familiar with that gem, but it seems like you should have your code in ApplicationController.

in ApplicationController:

```
@recommender = CourseRecommender.new

# Add records to the recommender.
@recommender.add_to_matrix!(:topics, "topic-1", "course-1")
@recommender.add_to_matrix!(:topics, "topic-2", "course-1")
@recommender.add_to_matrix!(:topics, "topic-1", "course-2")
```

and then in your controler:

```
class CourseController < ApplicationController
  def show
    # I would like to access the recommender here.
    similiar_courses = @recommender.similarities_for("course-1")
  end
end
```

Comment: Just to clarify, the code should go in the controller, and *not* in the initializer. You might also consider making it a filter if it is only required for certain requests.

Comment: Right. But I think it makes more sense to put the code in an initializer. Thanks anyway.